# Ruby/Rails: create a custom block/yield for http requests to avoid repetition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block, yield

I want to avoid too much copy/paste of http requests in my code, so I'm trying to create the following:

```
post "#{URL}/api/v1/notify" do
  header 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
  header 'Authorization', "Bearer 123456"

  success do
    # what to do in case of success
  end

  error do |e|
    # what to do in case of error
  end
end
```

But I'm having trouble creating the requred post method, so far

```
def post(url, &block)
  puts "post"
 
  url = URI("#{URL}/api/v1/notify")
  http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
  http.use_ssl = url.instance_of?(URI::HTTPS)

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url) # or GET
  request['Content-Type'] = #header content type
  request['Authorization'] = #header bearer
  response = http.request(request)

 response.success? ? success : failure
end

def success(&block)
  puts "success"
  yield
end

def error(&block)
  puts "error"
  yield
end
```

The method is supposed to replace the following code used multiple times everywhere:

```
url = URI("#{URL}/api/v1/notify")
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = url.instance_of?(URI::HTTPS)

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url) # or GET
request['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
request['Authorization'] = "Bearer 123456"
response = http.request(request)

if response.code == '200'
  #success
else
  #failure
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your own DSL around this:

```rb
class Client
  def self.post(&block)
    dsl = Dsl.new
    dsl.instance_eval(&block)

    # build request with data from dsl calls
    # and execute request
    puts "Making a request to #{dsl.url} with headers #{dsl.headers}"
    response = "response" # this would be your http response
    if rand > 0.5 # response.success?
      dsl.on_success.call(response) if dsl.on_success
    else
      dsl.on_error.call(response) if dsl.on_error
    end
  end

end

class Dsl
  def initialize
    @headers = {}
  end

  def url(*values)
    return @url if values.length == 0

    @url = values[0]
  end

  def headers
    @headers.freeze
  end

  def header(*values)
    return @headers[values.first] if values.length == 1

    @headers[values[0]] = values[1]
  end

  def on_success(&block)
    return @on_success if !block

    @on_success = block
  end

  def on_error(&block)
    return @on_error if !block

    @on_error = block
  end
end



Client.post do |client|
  url "http://somewhere"
  header "Kwazy", "Cupcakes"
  on_success do |response|
    puts "got #{response} which is a success"
  end

  on_error do |response|
    puts "gor #{response} which is an error"
  end
end
```

Obviously the distinction if you are calling a getter/setter via a variadic argument length is a bit special and could also be done by using real setter names (`url=`, ...) or by using different getter names (`get_url`)

THe somewhat special part is the `instance_eval(block)`. It allows to change `self` so that the receiver of the methods inside the `post` block is not `Client` but the `Dsl` instance.

This can cause troubles and makes a tad harder to debug. So you could also

`yield(dsl)` instead and then pass the dsl as an argument to the block.

```rb
Client.post do |dsl|
  dsl.url "http://somewhere"
  #...
end
```

Update:

Stefans proposal sounds good as well. I think he meant something like this (or check out his link in the comments):

```rb
class DslData
  attr_accessor :url
end


class Dsl
  attr_reader :dsl_data
  def initialize
    @dsl_data = DslData.new
  end 

  def url(value)
    dsl_data.url = value
  end
end

class Client
  def self.post
    dsl = Dsl.new
    dsl.instance_eval(&block)
    puts "Url: #{dsl.dsl_data.url}"
  end
end
```

Comment: You can avoid the combined getter / setter logic by having two classes: `DslData` with `attr_accessor :header, :on_success, :on_error` and `Dsl` which acts as a wrapper, proving just the DSL setters, e.g. `def header(key, value) ; @data.headers[key] = value ; end`.

Comment: @Stefan can you show an example? Thank you.

Comment: @Yassine like this: https://gist.github.com/sos4nt/ea681c2bc254b78e531877dd5287c8a5 – note that `post` is working solely with `DslData`, the `Dsl` class is just used as a temorary context for the block evaluation. (it's not even assigned to a variable)